# Angular routing for prefix with route parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, router, prefix

I want to implement the user profile page. It would be simple to just use the

`/profile/user123` path using:

*app-routing.module*

```js
{
  path: 'profile',
  loadChildren: () => import('./modules/profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule)
},
```

*profile-routing.module*

```js
{
  path: ':username',
  component: ProfileComponent
},
```

however, I want to do some fancy URL like `/@user123`.

Unfortunately, I did not find any clues on how to do it. I tried the following:

*app-routing.module*

```js
{
  path: '@:username',
  loadChildren: () => import('./modules/profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule)
},
```

*profile-routing.module*

```js
{
  path: '',
  component: ProfileComponent
},
```

but it didn't work.

There is only one thing that comes to my mind, which is using a **Guard** checking for the '@' prefix, otherwise redirect to the `/not-found` page.

Any ideas on how to do the routing using the "Angular" way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of custom route `matcher` to achieve the expected result.

- *app-routing.module.ts*

```ts
    {
      path: 'profile',
      loadChildren: () => import('./modules/profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule)
    },
```

- In *profile-routing.module.ts* you can specify a route by providing `custom URL-matching function` as:

```ts
    {
      matcher: (url) => {
        // You can have regex as per your requirement
        if (url.length === 1 && url[0].path.match(/^@[\w]+$/gm)) {
          return {
            consumed: url,
            posParams: {
              username: new UrlSegment(url[0].path.substr(1), {}) // <--- creating UrlSegment by getting rid of @ from url path
            }
          };
        }
    
        return null;
      },
      component: ProfileComponent
    }
```

- In *profile.component.ts* file you can read the `username` as:

```ts
    username$!: Observable<string | null>;
    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.username$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap
        .pipe(
          map((params: ParamMap) => params.get('username'))
        );
    }
```

- In *profile.component.html* you can print the username as:

```html
    <p>
        Profile: {{username$ | async}}
    </p>
```

- Now simply navigate to url `/profile/@user123` and you should be able to get `user123` as username in *ProfileComponent*

Comment: This solution worked with a little tweak, since I wanted to do `/@user123`, not `/profile/@user123`. Also, I added the hyphen in the regex. I will post the modified solution, but I accepted your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by [**Siddhant**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9471852/siddhant) is excellent, but I wanted `/@user123` instead of `/profile/@user123`, so I tweaked it a little.

*app-routing.module.ts*

```js
{
  matcher: (url) => {
    if (url.length === 1 && url[0].path.match(/^@[\w.\-]+$/gm)) { // <--- added a hyphen and a dot, since \w only does [a-zA-Z0-9_]
      return {
        consumed: url,
        posParams: {
          username: new UrlSegment(url[0].path.substr(1), {}) // <--- creating UrlSegment by getting rid of @ from url path
        }
      };
    }
    return null;
  },
  loadChildren: () => import('./modules/profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule)
},
```

*profile.routing.module.ts*

```js
{
  path: '',
  component: ProfileComponent
},
```

*profile.component.ts*

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
    this.userService.getUser(paramMap.get('username')).subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.user = res;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate([Utils.ARTICLE_NOT_FOUND_URL]);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding another answer, since I also needed to use the `@user123/edit` path, but it didn't work with the original solution. So here is how to do it:

*app-routing.module.ts*

```js
 {
    matcher: (url) => {
      console.log(url);
      if (url[0].path.match(/^@[\w.\-]+$/gm)) { <-- removed check for url length
        return {
          consumed: url.slice(0, 1), <-- return the rest of the URL instead of the whole URL (this routing rule should only consume @user123 and return the rest of the URL, which is /edit)
          posParams: {
            username: new UrlSegment(url[0].path.substr(1), {}) // <--- creating UrlSegment by getting rid of @ from url path
          }
        };
      }
      return null;
    },
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule)
  },
```

*profile.routing.module.ts*

```js
{
    path: '',
    component: ProfileComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'edit',
    component: EditProfileComponent
  },
```